# Team Foundation Server Copy File Paths

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe

I work in an environment where an Operations Center deploys our file changes into Production.

We just switched from Visual Source Safe to Team Foundation Server.

In VSS we were able to highlight the files, click the Tools menu, then select Files Report.  A dialog box would appear, and when you clicked Ok, the box went away, but the paths to the highlighted files would be copied into your clipboard.

We could then paste the clipboard contents into an IT Service Request, and the Operations folks would know exactly where in VSS the files were that they needed to move into Production servers.

It would look something like this:

$/BillingApplication12Client/TSEntry/TSEntryProd/BillingAppMain/bin:
BillingApp.exe
dtentry.dll
BillingAppReports.dll
CustomReportCtrl.dll

For the life of me I cannot find the same function in TFS.  Does anyone know how I can copy the file paths to the files I want deployed from the TFS?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you would need to see what files you need to release to operations. In TFS, this is done through release management, and it is very powerful technology, where you can automate a whole lot, including what you are trying to do. First, you may want to create a team build to build these applications and publish them as a build artifact. Then, you create a release definition where you can potentially run some tests and if they succeed, release the binaries to the production/operations. If you haven't see how the release process works, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/what-is-release-management?view=azure-devops